# Cerrar una ventana modal luego de publicar datos correctamente

Tags: jquery, material-design, material-design-lite

Estoy usando esta ventana [modal](http://ettrics.com/code/material-design-modal/) de material design el cual al hacer click en el boton cerrar cierra, esta misma funcion de ese boton quiero que la haga en el boton send al hacer click y cerrar luego de enviar los datos que se se me muestran en la ventana modal.

Aqui esta mi js

```
$('body').on('click', '.publisher_timeline_js', function(event) 
{

    var _this = $(this);

    var publisher = _this.parents('.timeline');
    /* get handle */
    var handle = publisher.attr('data-handle');
    /* get text */
    var textarea = publisher.find('textarea');
    var attachments = publisher.find('.publisher-time-attach');
    var photos = publisher.data('uploading');
    var link = publisher.data('scrabing');

    $.post(api['/stream/store'], {'handle': handle, 'message': textarea.val(), 'photos': JSON.stringify(photos), 'datas': JSON.stringify(link)}, function(response) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(link));
        if (response.callback) {
            eval(response.callback);
        } else {
            textarea.val('');
            publisher.removeData('uploading');
            $('.publisher-timeline').html('').fadeOut();

            $('.file_up_drop').show();
            publisher.removeData('scrabing');
            attachments.hide();
            attachments.find('li.item').remove();

            //AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO QUE CIERRE LA VENTANA MODAL 

            if (response.message.type == 'photo') {

            } else if (response.message.type == 'link') {

            } else if (response.message.type == 'video') {

            } else if (response.message.type == 'rich') {

            } else if (response.message.type == 'text') {

            }

            //$('.timeline-publisher').prepend(template);
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aqui hay una opcion vastante simple:
Código Javascript
onclick=”window.opener.location.reload(); window.close();”

esto es si utilizas una ventana emergente con iframe
https://thorv.wordpress.com/2006/12/27/javascript-actualizar-ventana-padre-desde-popup/

si lo haces con un div en la misma pagina revisa los botones close de un ejemplo modal.

Comment: Gracias me fue util

Answer (score 0):

No se si todavía lo necesites o no se si funcione, pero podrías intentar usando algo como

```
$("#idmodal").fadeOut();
```

No se si funcione, pero es un idea sencilla.

Comment: No me funciona ya que la libreria que uso abre varios elemento al cerrarlos quedan aun abierto. lo que necesito es algo que cuando cargue la ventana modal con texto en el textarea al darle publicar me cierre la ventana y publique su contenido

Answer (score -2):

`location.reload();` 
Al darle confirmar al `submit` de publicar al segundo se cierra y te refresca la página.